# Get the Sum of the result of map() ES6

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, ecmascript-6, sum

Here's the updated code that reads all the contents in subfiles, returns all integers in a single array and returns the sum of all the items in the array:

```
const fs = require('fs')

let output = (file) => {
  let data = fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf8')
    .split('\n')
    .reduce((array, i) => {
      if (i.match(/.txt$/)) {
        let intArr = array.concat(output(i))
        return intArr
      } else if (i.match(/^\d+$/)) {
        array.push(parseInt(i, 10));
      }
      return array;
    }, [])

    return data
}

console.log(output('a.txt')) // single array

const sum = output('a.txt')

console.log(sum.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)) // sum of array contents
```

---

I'm trying to get the result of the following code into a single array so I can get the sum of all the numbers. Consider that the contents of the file `a.txt` are

```
1
b.txt
```

the contents of `b.txt` are

```
2
c.txt
```

and the contents of `c.txt` are

```
3
```

The code is as follows:

```
const fs = require('fs')
let output = (file) => {
  let data = fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf8')
    .split('\n')
    .map((i) => {
      return i
    })

  let subData = data
    .filter(value => /.txt$/.test(value))
    .map((i) => {
      output(i)
      return i
    })

  let intData = data
    .filter(value => /^\d+$/.test(value))
    .map((i) => {
      return parseInt(i, 10)
    })
  console.log(intData)
}

output('a.txt')
```

This outputs:

```
[3]
[2]
[1]
```

Which would be the best way of getting the sum of these numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your code by using the [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method instead of `.map`:

> The `reduce()` method applies a function against an accumulator and each element in the array (from left to right) to reduce it to a single value.

```
const fs = require('fs')
let output = (file) => {
  let data = fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf8')
    .split('\n')
    .reduce((sum, i) => {
      if (i.match(/.txt$/)) {
        sum += output(i);
      } else if (i.match(/^\d+$/)) {
        sum += parseInt(i, 10);
      }
      return sum;
    }, 0)
}
```

---

If you want to save the integers in an array you could reduce it to an array instead:

```
const fs = require('fs')
let output = (file) => {
  let data = fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf8')
    .split('\n')
    .reduce((array, i) => {
      if (i.match(/.txt$/)) {
        array.concat(output(i));
      } else if (i.match(/^\d+$/)) {
        array.push(parseInt(i, 10));
      }
      return array;
    }, [])
}
```

Then if you want to get the sum of the file `a.txt` do:

```
const sum = output('a.txt').map((sum,i) => sum + i);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. Unfortunately, this is returning `undefined`.

Comment: @Ale, Ops forgot to pass in the starting `acc` value `0`. By default starting `acc` value is the first element of the reduced array: here a string. Does it work now?

Comment: Here's a test without using the regex conditions and without having depth to the file: [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uwo9L87z/16/)

Comment: Oh! Thanks :) I think it doesn't apply to my problem because I'm trying to read the context of a file a.txt and the subfile b.txt, and at the same time the content of c.txt which is within b.txt, and so on and so forth... So my problem lies in that I was able to get each of the numeric values and exclude the .txt, but I have each of the integers in it's own array. If I could only get all those integers in a single array, I could add them up, and that's where I'm stuck :S

Comment: So you do have an array with all integers?

Comment: I guess the main question is how do I sum up the output that I already have in the code above, or which would be the best approach for doing this?

Comment: Exactly, I'm stuck in getting that output into an array and manipulating those values.

Comment: Not, unfortunately! You can't map the a.txt directly. Thanks for your help, anyway!

Comment: @Ale You looked too far down. Check my answer *starting from* "If you want to save the integer..."

Comment: Oh yeah, this is the thing: Each one of the integers is in its own array, [1][2][3][4]... I'm stuck on the sum of these, but since they are separated, I can't seem to achieve my goal. How do I get these values and sum them together? :D it's a doozie!

Comment: @Ale, Do you mean you've got `[ [1], [2], [3] ]`? If so try `a.reduce((sum, curr) => sum + curr[0], 0)` then ;)

Comment: Hi @Ivan No, I mean I've literally got [1] [2] [3], and my headache lies precisely in getting [ [1] [2] [3] ], if I had a nested array, I'd be able to make the sum, but I'm not able to get these inside the same array. :)

Comment: @Ale, This is confusing where are you getting these values from? Did you use my code with the `.reduce` method? If not, are you still using your code and logging the values separately?

Comment: Hi @Ivan, sorry about that. Please see the code above again, run it and you'll see what I'm talking about. I'm getting the values by mapping a.txt, selecting out the ints, reading b.txt inside a.txt, c.txt inside b.txt, so on and so forth, and selecting out those integers, they get spit out in the console.log(i) on line 21 in the form of: `[3] [2] [1]`

Comment: @Ale, I know you are logging them, you asked: "how to save them in an array to later sum the different numbers". I replied with an edit that allowed to do that, but it seems you haven't tested it...

Comment: You're right, I've posted the full code that returns all items in a single array and also the sum of these. Brilliant, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Below uses the promisified version of readFile, I've left it intentionally a bit verbose to demonstrate what's going on, you could obviously simplify/shorten that a bit.

However, it takes an array of files, filters out every number and sums all of them

```
const fs = require('fs');
const {promisify} = require('util');
const readFileAsync = promisify(fs.readFile); 

function readAndSum(file) {
  return readFileAsync(file, 'utf8')
    .then(f => f.split('\n'))
    .then(lines => {
      return lines.map(line => {
        let newFile = line.match(/\w+\.txt/);
        if (newFile) {
            return readAndSum(newFile[0]);
        }
        return Number(line);
      })
    })
    .then(t => Promise.all(t.reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), [])))
    .then(numbers => numbers.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0))
}

readAndSum('foo.txt').then(sum => console.log(sum));
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Though, this method removes the ability to look for integers in subfiles recursively, doesn't it? Which is what is making this difficult... How can I sum up [1][2][3][4] (anonymous arrays) or get [1][2][3][4] into a single named array and add them up? :D Thanks again!

Comment: A sorry, @Ale, I didn't read that part of the requirement... I've edited the answer to read file by file

Comment: Brilliant! This is working perfectly! I'll see if I can get a less verbose version and post it here. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. Some of the `then`s can be omitted and packed in a single block.. @Ale